# How to use mongodb's increments operator ($inc) in prisma ORM?

Tags: mongodb, prisma

I cannot find a way to use some special MongoDB operation on prisma:
In MongoDB I can do this:

```
mongodb>  db.products.updateOne(
   { sku: "abc123" },
   { $inc: { quantity: -2 } }
)
```

How to do this in prisma?

```
await this.prismaService.product.update({
      where: { sku: "abc123" },
      data: {
        quantity: {"$inc": -2}, // this will not work
      },
    });
```

Comment: Is there any way out there without running $runCommandRaw ?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't found any solution.
I use raw query instead:

```
this.prisma.$runCommandRaw({
      'update': 'app_caches',
      'updates': [
        {
          'q': { '_id': 'nft_failed_count' },
          'u': { '$inc': { 'value': 1000 } },
          'multi': false,
          'upsert': true,
        },
      ],
    })
```